# Have a javascript ready, need to insert commas in numerical results

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have cobbled together a script that takes a variable, does two separate math computations to it, and displays both answers on the screen.

I need for the script to place commas into both "generated" answers when the results exceed 1,000. (Notice, default values appearing in the HTML already have commas in place.)

However, I do not need for the results to show any trailing decimal points.

Here's my JavaScript and some accompanying HTML...

```js
function return_selected(currentID) {
  var savings = document.getElementById(currentID);
  var valueCalc = savings.options[savings.selectedIndex].value;
  return valueCalc;
}

// computing potential at 3%
function firstCalc() {
  var calcPrice1 = return_selected('soldfor') * .03 - 595;
  document.getElementById('savings3').innerHTML = "$" + calcPrice1;
  return calcPrice1;
}

// computing potential at 6%
function secondCalc() {
  var calcPrice2 = return_selected('soldfor') * .06 - 595;
  document.getElementById('savings6').innerHTML = "$" + calcPrice2;
  return calcPrice2;
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", firstCalc);
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", secondCalc);
// should listen for all select option
document.addEventListener("change", firstCalc);
document.addEventListener("change", secondCalc);
```

```html
<!--HTML Routine to DISPLAY COMPUTATIONS -->**

<div class="box">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Start with this number
      <select name="" id="soldfor">
            <option value="100000">$100,000</option>
            <option value="200000">$200,000</option>
            <option value="300000">$300,000</option>
            <option value="400000" selected>$400,000</option>
            <option value="450000">$450,000</option>
          </select>
    </p>Compute a new number <span id="savings3">$11,405</span>
    <p>
      <p>and compute another number
        <span id="savings6">$23,405</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Numbers in modern javascript have a `.toLocaleString()` method and the Math object has always had round/floor/ceil functions to remove decimal points as required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function addComma(val) {
    while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())) {
        val = val.toString().replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})/, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return val;
}

var calcPrice1 = 100000 * .03 - 595;
document.getElementById('savings3').innerHTML = "$" + addComma(Math.trunc(calcPrice1));

var calcPrice2 = 100000 * .06 - 595;
document.getElementById('savings6').innerHTML = "$" + addComma(Math.trunc(calcPrice2));
```

It will work for you.

Comment: Thanks so much (to everyone) for helping this neophyte navigate through a tough situation!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Number.toLocaleString()` to format numbers according to Locale conventions.

```
var n1 = 1e5;
var n2 = 1e6;

console.log('n1:',n1.toLocaleString());
//=> n1: 100,000
console.log('n2:',n2.toLocaleString());
//=> n2: 1,000,000
```

See [Number.prototype.toLocaleString() @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString).

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!Number.prototype.toMoney) {
    Number.prototype.toMoney = function () {                   
        return this.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    };
}

console.log((4500000.00).toMoney()); // 4,500,000
```

OR

```
var format = function (n) {                   
  return n.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
};

console.log(format(10500)); // 10,500
```